# c++: smart pointer in STL

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

Here is my code:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(){ cout << "constructor" << endl; }
    ~Test(){ cout << "destructor" << endl; }
    void show(){ cout << "show" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Test>> vec;
    vec.push_back(make_shared<Test>(Test()));
    vec[0]->show();
    vec.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

I run the code above in Visual Studio and here is the result:

```
constructor
destructor
show
destructor
```

In my opinion, `constructor` and `destructor` before `show` come from `Test()`. We created a temporary object as the parameter of `make_shared<>()`. So here we call the constructor and destructor.
But I don't know why there isn't any `constructor` after `show`. Won't `make_shared` new an object? How could we have a `destructor` without any `constructor` after `show`? Or it's because the compiler did something that I don't know?

Comment: `make_shared<Test>()` should suffice, you are not printing a copy-constructor

Comment: `make_shared<Test>(Test())` <-- looks like you're doing some copy-constructing here. Is that intentional? Why not just `make_shared<Test>()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gotta be aware of compiler-generated copy constructors here (or elided copies depending on compiler implementation):

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(){ cout << "constructor" << endl; }
    ~Test(){ cout << "destructor" << endl; }
    Test(const Test& other){cout << "copy" << std::endl;}
    void show(){ cout << "show" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Test>> vec;
    vec.push_back(make_shared<Test>(Test()));
    vec[0]->show();
    vec.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

> constructor 
> copy
> destructor
> show
> destructor

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7e7d77899c70e32)

The generation of a copy constructor when there is a user defined destructor is [deprecated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), so in our case the compiler is either eliding the copy, or actually generating a copy constructor.

#### Edit

A word to the wise. The Rule of Three has become the Rule of Five (and a half) in C++11 and beyond. I personally like the [Rule of all or nothing](http://arne-mertz.de/2015/02/the-rule-of-zero-revisited-the-rule-of-all-or-nothing/) which essentially states that if you define any one of the special member functions (ctors, dtor, assignment), then you should define ALL of them (explicitly default or delete them, that is)

Comment: with a user-provided destructor the compiler doesn't generate a move-constructor

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Updated language to mention elided copies and/or possibility of compiler-generating the copy ctor, which is still possible though deprecated with user defined dtor.

Comment: It's hard to keep track of all the scenarios where the compiler will and won't generate special member functions!